# GPG error on Debian

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I followed below link

http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian

But when I run below command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

Error comes:

```
mucip@debian-ev:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.YxA1unHkRT/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.YxA1unHkRT/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
mucip@debian-ev:~$
```

What is the problem?...

Regards,
Mucip:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264654/gpg-error-on-debian/) by [Mucip](https://answers.ros.org/users/30896/mucip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-24**:
Please use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to format console copy-pastes. That makes them much easier to read.

Thanks.

**Comment by [Mucip](https://answers.ros.org/users/30896/mucip/) on 2017-06-24**:
Hi,
You're right. Sorry. I will use this next time...

**Comment by [Mucip](https://answers.ros.org/users/30896/mucip/) on 2017-06-24**:
Hi,
I applied format. Thanks. I am learning... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
After than Gvdhoorn's answer. I googled little bitr more. I installed below packets;
su

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg
sudo apt-get install dirmngr
```

Than redo below code,

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key s421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

Than now everything fine again... ;-)

Regards,
Mucip:)

---

Originally posted by [Mucip](https://answers.ros.org/users/30896/mucip/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1